# AngularJS ng-repeat, tables information dependencies

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created two tables in server side. The first one contains informations like house, room house, number, street ...

The second one contains informations like first_color, room house, second_color ...

Of course both tables have different number of columns and rows. For instance the first one has 5 rows and the second one only 2 rows (rows increase dynamically).

As you read before they both have one common information the "room house" data.
I need to change colors information of the first table with information of the second one depending on that link field 'room house'.

Here bellow is my HTML code using two times "ng-repeat" :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in data.house | orderBy: '-count' | limitTo: data.limit">
     <div ng-repeat="d in data.colors" ng-show="d.room_house == item.room_house">
        <span style="color:{{::d.firsrt_color}}">{{::item.name}}</span>
     </div>
     <div>
        <span style="color:#444444">{{::item.name}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

However if the common information can't be find it doesn't display the rest of the table. I need to display the whole information within the first table with the color information inside the second one. If information can't be found (due to different numbers of rows between the two arrays or because data doesn't exist in the second one) I must continue to display information of the first array however with a default color.

Of course adding an html div with ng-show="d.room_house != item.room_house" doesn't work because it will display some information in two colors. 
[Controller 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob4qD.png)

[Controller 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08KaT.png)

Hope someone will be able to help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of nested loops in HTML, you can move the logic to your controller and your HTML looks smaller and cleaner and the original issue will also be fixed.
Try this solution,

```js
var defaultColor = "#444444";
data.house.forEach(function(house) {
  house.color = defaultColor; // assign default color initially
  var obj = data.colors.filter(function(x){
     return x.room_house == house.room_house;
  }
  if(obj.length > 0) {
    house.color = obj[0].firsrt_color;
  } 
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in data.house | orderBy: '-count' | limitTo: data.limit">
     <div>
        <span ng-style="{ color: item.color}">{{::item.name}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

P.S: You've used "firsrt_color" instead of "first_color", I hope that's intended..

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your help !
I will continue with what you said and console.log. I think the hardest part is that I have to compiled my code inside a specific platform and its restrictions that include. 
I have this error : Expected an identifier and instead of saw '>'

PS: Yes I wrote it too fast haha but no mistake because I copy pasted the englsih written mistake.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you getting an error message ?

Comment: Yes sorry I pushed "Enter" I didn't finished to write my whole sentence.

Comment: Did you paste the javascript code in the right place inside your angularjs controller ? Please share your angularjs snippet and full error message from browser console

Comment: I added controller 1 and controller 2 images inside my post

Comment: Try the updated code in my answer. Apparently, there is no ES6 support in the browser you tried.

Comment: You are awesome it works. I put it inside the server part (I don't get why it didn't work inside the cotroller part), must be linked to the platform. 
Thank you for your help !